# How to create a UserControl that is a bitmap in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I was the functionality of a UserControl but I want it to look like a bitmap.  How can I do this in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the `Image` control? What exactly do you want? How does a bitmap look like? Can you write more than one sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

1. Download [source of the Bitmap class that will snap to device pixels from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx)
2. Rewrite it a little bit.
   a. Set `UserControl` instead of `UIElement` as it's parent
   b. Rename `MeasureCore` to `MeasureOverride`

I hope that will become the thing you need.